# How to get styled text from TextView

Tags: android, textview

Quite simple problem:

1. I have some TextView

   ```
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   ```
2. I set styled text (with `<b>` tags or any other tags)

   ```
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Simple text. <b>Bold text</b>. Simple text."));
   ```

**Problem**: when I call `textView.getText()` I receive `Simple text. Bold text. Simple text.`. `<b>` tags have disappeared somehow.

How can I retrieve text from TextView with its formatting?

Comment: Are you just hard-coding the string? Why not just keep the original String somewhere, such as a static-final?

Comment: My guess is that you will have to play with Html.toHtml() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml(android.text.Spanned))  and  TextView.getEditableText() as Editable is  derived from "Spanned" which is input for Html.toHtml. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html

Comment: @Karakuri There are lots of strings and they will change at the runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Wand Maker's assumption (see comments in question) was correct

Following code works:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Simple text. <b>Bold text</b>. Simple text."), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
String almostSameText = Html.toHtml(tv.getEditableText()).toString();
```

The result is: `<p>Simple text. <b>Bold text</b>. Simple text</p>`