# Get text from Html styled TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView which contains text with Html attributes like subscription,
for example it's a chemical formula H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>. How can I get this text from textview,  but with subscriptions (String isn't showing the subscript)

here you can see screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u9vtmqaxdnqfy5/Capture.PNG

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get styled text from TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491126/how-to-get-styled-text-from-textview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set **H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>** in textview,Use `subscript` tag as

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

where `textview` is your Textview's tag.

And get text from textview as

```
String str = Html.toHtml(textview.getEditableText()).toString();
anothertextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

For more info see [Selecting, Highlighting, or Styling Portions of Text](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext)

Comment: I need to get the text from other textview

Comment: String str = Html.toHtml(textview.getEditableText()).toString(); it's not working

Comment: @user3162875 do you want this text "H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>"

Comment: no I want to take a text like that from on textview and copy paste on the other one

Comment: dont use Html class,  its the most **inefficient** solution when dealing with Spanned classes

Comment: @user3162875 Happy to help,enjoy coding.and don't forget to accept it,so it may help others having similar issue.

Comment: @GiruBhai no it wont help as its the most inefficient solution i ever seen

Comment: @pskink yes I know,that span is best,but I am not familiar with this more.So I will learn and post that also.

Comment: so please dont encourage other people to use those inefficient workarounds

Comment: if the text of textview is already defined how must i use this
 TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE

Comment: @user3162875 yes because toHtml use for getEditableText()

Comment: I have a textview with already defined text how should I do

Comment: @user3162875 just call secondTextView.setText(firstTextView.getText())